Removing a datagridview from a splitcontainer
I have a splitcontainer that has a number of different controls in the panels. I would like to dynamically remove the datagridview if it is in the splitcontainer. While this code exicutes and gives no errors it does not remove the datagridview.
For i = scExspenses.Panel1.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If TypeOf scExspenses.Panel1.Controls(i) Is DataGridView Then
        scExspenses.Controls.Remove(scExspenses.Panel1.Controls(i))
    End If
Next

I know that I can remove all controls with scExspenses.Controls.Clear() but I do not want to destroy the other controls that are in the splitcontainer panel

I don't think you read your own code very well. You index Panel1.Controls to get the control, then you try to remove it from the SplitContainer itself instead of Panel1. You need to remove it from the Controls collection it's actually in, which would be the one you're indexing.

Thank you and you are correct, but that did not solve my issue. I did solve the issue by doing a dispose instead of a remove. So the scExspenses.Panel1.Controls(i).Dispose() worked.

The main issue is that you're trying to remove the control from the wrong Controls collection. You get it from scExspenses.Panel1.Controls but then try to remove it from scExspenses.Controls, which is obviously not going to work. Assuming there will never be more than one DataGridView control in that container, I would ditch the loop and do it like this:
Dim dgv = scExspenses.Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)().FirstOrDefault()

If dgv IsNot Nothing Then
    scExspenses.Panel1.Controls.Remove(dgv)
End If

If you want to be able to use the grid again later then you need to retain a reference to it. If you don't want to use it later then you should dispose it, thus releasing all its resources. That simplifies this even more:
scExspenses.Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)().FirstOrDefault()?.Dispose()

The ?. operator incorporates a null check so you don't need to do it explicitly. Disposing the control will automatically remove it from its container. I'm not sure whether disposing takes care of all the data in the grid but you might want to either set the DataSource to Nothing or Clear the Rows collection to remove all the data too.
